# Fragmenting Data from a Data Frame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, append

So I am just starting out with Python and have a confusing task at hand. I have this dataframe of 100 elements with an column of 'counter' going from 1 to 10, and repeating 10 times.

Now, I want to split this dataframe into 10 different dataframes based on the counter.
I have tried using for loop and conditional statements to reset the loop when the counter goes back to 1, but then I am losing on the 10th element.

I hope I am able to explain my problem well.

Kindly guide me. I just need a direction about how to proceed in a situation like this.

Cheers!

Comment: How do you want it split? do you want one df of where Counter column is 1, another where it is 2 and so on? or split into each count 1-10 then start a new df (assuming counter column is sorted in a way that makes this possible).

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

# creating mock df
df = pd.DataFrame([{'counter':e,'col_name':'some_value'} for e in 
range(1,11)])
df = pd.concat([df,df]).reset_index() 

#slicing the df at every 10nth index
splitted_dfs = [df.iloc[e-10:e,:] for e in range(10,len(df)+1,10)]
```

You are probably loosing the 10th element because `range(x,y)` includes `y-1` and not `y`.